# Abrir teclado en pantalla en tableta con Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, windows10, teclado

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación `Windows forms` con `visual basic`.

Esta aplicación trabajará en una tableta con `Windows 10`, el problema es que cuando presiono sobre un `textbox` el teclado táctil no se despliega, únicamente sucede cuando son `combobox` o `richtextbox`, he estado buscando información al respecto pero no he encontrado nada.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias abrir el proceso

```
Imports System.IO



            Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink"
            Dim keyBPath As String = Path.Combine(folderPath, "TabTip.exe")
            Process.Start(keyBPath)
```